# How to make an UI component from several UI compontents

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view

Friends,

I created an UI component "compTV" that extends Textview. It works very well. 
Now i want to create an UI compoentent "3compTV" that just consists out of 3 "compTV" ´s next to each other.

The code, creating a LinearLayout and add 3 "compTV" ´s works very well if i just extend Activity. 
But how to create a Component out of this? 
What class do i have to extend for the "3compTV" component and what else would be necessary. 
When i extend compTV only one object will be drawn. So i guess i have to extend a different class or take some other approach to this problem.

Thanks for your support

```
    public class 3compTV extends compTV{

Context ctx;
int layoutMaringLeft = 100;
int layoutMaringRight = 0;
int layoutMaringTop = 0;
int layoutMaringBottom = 0;
int amountOfComponents = 5;

public components(Context context) {
    super(context);
    ctx = context;
    Log.d(ctx.getString(R.string.app_name), "components, Constructor1");
    compTV comp1 = new compTV(ctx);
    compTV comp2 = new compTV(ctx);
    compTV comp3 = new compTV(ctx);

    comp2.setLetter("A");
    comp2.setState("grey");
    comp3.setLetter("A");
    comp3.setState("grey");
    LinearLayout LL2 = new LinearLayout(ctx);
    LL2.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    layoutParams.setMargins(layoutMaringLeft, layoutMaringTop,
            layoutMaringRight, layoutMaringBottom);

    LL2.addView(comp1, layoutParams);

    comp1.setLetter("H");
    comp1.setState("green");
    LL2.addView(comp2, layoutParams);
    LL2.addView(comp3, layoutParams);

}

public components(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    ctx = context;
    Log.d(ctx.getString(R.string.app_name), "components, Constructor2");


}

public components(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    ctx = context;
    Log.d(ctx.getString(R.string.app_name), "components, Constructor3");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a view that extends `LinearLayout` and contains 3 instances of `compTV`.

```
public class 3CompTV extends LinearLayout {

    public 3CompTV(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            addView(new CompTV(context));      
        }  
    }
}
```

My personal preference would be to put the 3 CompTV views in an XML layout, with their parent element being `<merge>`.  This allows you to specify their attributes like `wrap_content` in XML, which I find much cleaner.  You add them to your custom view like this:

```
public class 3CompTV extends LinearLayout {

    public 3CompTV(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        View.inflate(context, R.id.three_comp_tvs, this);           
    }
}
```